# How to change the order of MySQL date output for my website

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm not that familiar with MySQL yet, but I'm practicing. I'd like to change my date order for my "mysql" in my PHP site.

Right now it is ("yyyy-mm-dd"), and I want it to be complete opposite, ("dd-mm-yyyy") like the German way.

This is my code so far, and I don't know if it is in MySQL or in PHP I can change it.

```
<?php
$data = "SELECT * FROM anmeldelser WHERE Kundenavn = 'Ludvig Andersen'";

$result = $connection->query($data);

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
      echo "<b>Kundenavn:&nbsp;</b>" . $row['Kundenavn'] .
           "<b>&nbsp;Kommentar:&nbsp;</b>" . $row['Kommentar'] .
           "<b>&nbsp;Dato:&nbsp;</b>" . $row['Dato'] . "<br><br>";

 }

?>
```

Comment: Personally, I would handle issues of localization in the front end, using javascript or php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
      echo "<b>Kundenavn:&nbsp;</b>" . $row['Kundenavn'] .
       "<b>&nbsp;Kommentar:&nbsp;</b>" . $row['Kommentar'] .
       "<b>&nbsp;Dato:&nbsp;</b>" . date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['Dato']) . "<br><br>";

 }
```

Comment: Hi mate. I tried it a couple of times, and found out that there were missing a ")" after the row, and that is why it didn't work. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

See below is your MySQL query which return all columns in table anmeldelser

```
$data = "SELECT * FROM anmeldelser WHERE Kundenavn = 'Ludvig Andersen'";
```

You can convert your date in your prefer format while retrieving data from database table I mean in above query.

So your query should look like as below:

```
$data = "SELECT col1,col2...,DATE_FORMAT(dato, '%d-%m-%Y') as dato FROM anmeldelser WHERE Kundenavn = 'Ludvig Andersen'";
```

Read more [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Hope it works for you

Comment: i tried to use your solution mate, but i couldn't make it work with it. It still says an error. Could you tell me if i'm doing it wrong here?

$data = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dato, '%d-%m-%Y') as dato * FROM anmeldelser WHERE Kundenavn = 'Ludvig Andersen'";